# C# different MSDN guidelines about Equals implementation

Tags: c#, equals, equality, msdn

Why do the following documents talk about different approaches when implementing `Equals` method?

- [`[MSDN]` Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx)
- [`[MSDN]` Implementing the Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh.aspx)

The second document *(which is more recent)* does not explicitly implement the strongly-typed version of `Equals` (like `public bool Equals(MySuperTrooperClass o)`).

What's underlying reason to drop the strongly-typed method from one of the guidelines and which approach should I use in my production code?

Comment: The strongly-typed one should really only be used if the type implements IEquatable<T>. Strangely, neither of those guides mention IEquatable<T>...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no benefit to dropping the strongly-typed version. Quite the contrary, as the first page itself mentions

> It is also recommended that in addition to implementing Equals
>   (object), any class also implement Equals (type) for their own type,
>   to enhance performance.

This is doubly true for value types.

I assume that the second page does not concern itself with this at all because only the weakly typed version is defined on `System.Object`. The strongly typed version typically goes hand in hand with implementing `IEquatable<T>`, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) for which mentions the interaction between `Equals(T)` and `Equals(object)`.

Answer (score 2):

An unfortunate side-effect of Microsoft's decision to overload `Equals` in many primitive types is that there are many cases where even though `((Object)X).Equals(Y)` will behave as an equivalence relation (which it should), because of implicit conversions, `X.Equals(Y)` will not.  For example, `3.Equals(3.0)` will return false, but `(3.0).Equals(3)` will return true.  While the `==` operator isn't quite as bad (generally if `X==Y`, `Y==X`) it still doesn't specify an equivalence relation (e.g. if X = Int64.MaxValue, Y=X-1, and Z=(Double)X, then X==Z and Y==Z but X!=Y).

Perhaps the reason that Microsoft dropped the advice about providing an overload of `Equals()` which behaves identically to `Equals(Object)` is that while implicit casts may render the former incapable of behaving as an equivalence relation, the latter should behave as an equivalence relation, with no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement strongly-typed Equals to enhance performance. As is it is written in first article

Answer (score 0):

When you want to check if two things has the same value you use the == 
When you want to check if two things are actually refrencing to the same instance you use Equals().

Keep in mind that only if Equals() is true, == must be true as well.

Regarding GetHashCode() - in some cases containing structures such as Dictionary use this specific method to distinguish between data. It is up to you to decide how your data should be distinguished, Yet GetHashCode() must not be changed while values of the object being changed to work correct. Meaning it should retain the same value during the object life-time.

When you do somthing like that:

```
MyClass A = new MyClass();
MyClass B = A;
```

When you check if (A==B) you actually check if pointer A address has the same Value as pointer B address.
So, you don't need to implement Equals() in 99.99% of common development.